# Connection string error to postgres using SSL certificates in c#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ssl, npgsql

I am trying to connect my .NET Web Api project to postgres database server using SSL connection and I am getting this error:

`{ "error": "The key contents do not contain a PEM, the content is malformed, or the key does not match the certificate." }`

I configured the server to require server certificates and put the client certificates(.crt, .key) and rootCA in my connection string. Here's how it looks:

`"DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Database=database1;Username=postgres;Password=pass; SSL Mode=VerifyFull; SSL Certificate=C:\\SSL\\clientpostgres.crt; SSL Key=C:\\SSL\\clientpostgresKey.key; Root Certificate=C:\\SSL\\rootCA.crt;"`

It doesn't matter if the SSL Mode is VerifyCA or VerifyFull, it doesn't work.

Comment: What if you don't use client certs at all, and just provide the rootCA for use with the server's cert?

Comment: That error message seems aggressively unhelpful.  Can you try to use a different tool (like `psql`) and see if that provides a better error?